# Using php to count rows in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count all rows from demos table but i got an error
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\working_scripts\test_2.php on line 8`
My php code is:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo"Error connecting to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}
$comment_counter=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM demos");
echo $comment_counter;
?>
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass a column name in `COUNT` function!

Comment: @BasitSaeed, no, `count(*)` is completely valid. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: So, u know what problem is? :D

Comment: mysqli_query returns an object: http://nz2.php.net/mysqli_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**mysqli_fetch_array**](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo"Error connecting to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM demos");

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row["total"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo"Error connecting to database". mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM demos');
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    echo $row["total"];
?>
```

OR

```
$result =  mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM demos'));
echo $result;
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but mind-404 already explained it.Thank u anway :D